# CakePHP ordered behavior with multiple foreign keys

Tags: cakephp, behavior

CakePHP does not have a built in mechanism for handling reordering of records, as far as I know. So, I'm using the [Ordered Behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2008/09/21/orderedbehavior-2-1) that, as near as I can tell, is the defacto behavior for reordering in CakePHP.  So far it's working well as I add it to various models, however, I've got a situation I'm not sure how to deal with.

My model hierarchy is as follows.

`Section > Heading > Category > Item`

However, Items can be attached directly to sections:

`Section > Item`

The Item model's table has both `category_id` and `section_id` defined, though only one is actually used for any given record.

The ordered behavior has two parameters set when you set the model's `$actsAs`.  Here's the one for my Heading model:

```
var $actsAs = array('Ordered' => array('field' => 'order','foreign_key' => 'section_id'));
```

How should I define the `$actsAs` member for the Item model where it has two foreign keys `section_id` and `category_id` to ensure that the ordering/sequence is properly maintained?

Comment: To get an answer, you'll likely need to add an example of the input you are giving and the output you are hoping for.  I can't quite understand what effect you are trying to create.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inputs.  What I have is a model that can be a child of one of two models and the ordered behavior maintains ordering for a given group of models based on a foreign key so the Items attached to Category X are ordered independent of the Items attached to Category Y, Section A, and Section B.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: It would require substantial changes for this. I would recommend having "invisible" categories for the "section items".

Comment: @AlexanderMorland thanks for the recommendation and thanks for contributing this piece of code to the community.  Without having to rework all of my existing data hierarchy, I found a solution that seems to work.  If you see anything in it that you think might be problematic, let me know, but so far it seems to be doing what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this extensively, but with my first try this appears to be a workaround that will let me dynamically manage the ordering.  Inside of my `ItemsController` I've got the following actions:

```
    function moveup($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for Item', true));
        } else {
            $item = $this->Item->read(null, $id);

            if ($item['Item']['section_id'] != 0) {
                $this->Item->Behaviors->attach('Ordered', array('field' => 'order', 'foreign_key'=>'section_id'));
            } else {
                $this->Item->Behaviors->attach('Ordered', array('field' => 'order', 'foreign_key'=>'category_id'));
            }

            if ($this->Item->moveup($id)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Item moved up', true));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Item move failed', true));
            }
        }

        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    function movedown($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for Item', true));
        } else {
            $item = $this->Item->read(null, $id);

            if ($item['Item']['section_id'] != 0) {
                $this->Item->Behaviors->attach('Ordered', array('field' => 'order', 'foreign_key'=>'section_id'));
            } else {
                $this->Item->Behaviors->attach('Ordered', array('field' => 'order', 'foreign_key'=>'category_id'));
            }

            if ($this->Item->movedown($id)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Item moved down', true));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Item move failed', true));
            }
        }

        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
```

My model doesn't set the ordered behavior (and thus the `foreign_key`) via the `$actsAs` member.  Instead, prior to any order manipulation, I determine the parent item type and attach the behavior, with appropriate `foreign_key` at run time.

Comment: I guess the biggest issue I see with this is that it violates the MVC pattern by putting what ought to be model logic into the controller.  Anyone have a suggestion for how this could be built into the model?